# Trying to set up my VPS server as a proxy server

Tags: networking, server, proxy

I am trying to set up my VPS server as a proxy server using [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-server-on-linux/)
while setting up, I found out that my server does not have a private IP, so I am trying to assign a private IP using [this guide](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/add-private-ip-ubuntu-server/)

Now, I am asked to add these commands, which I did:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address XX.XX.XX.XX <--- Private IP address
    netmask 255.255.255.0 <--- Subnet Mask for Private IP range
```

Now my interfaces file looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I do

```
sudo ifup eth1
```

I get this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQrBy.png]

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me to set up the VPS as a proxy server?

Thank you!